# Nodejs - how to make a quick get request without waiting for the answer

Tags: node.js

I need to run a nodejs script that can send sequenced get http requests that may or may not be responded.

This means that i can start by requesting , per example, 10.0.0.1  until 10.0.0.10 but it is possible that 10.0.0.4 and 10.0.0.5 does not exist at a given moment but i dont want that fact to slow down the requests to the other ip addresses and the reply of each ip address is not relevant. I don’t even read the reply. I just want to make the fastest and “blindest” request i can without nothing slowing down that process.

How can i acheive that?

Using xmlhttprequest as async. (I think. I’m not an experienced programmer or what-so-ever)
But i could use some help on “how would you do it”.

I’m using this to control some led lights that change color on the get request. I might not have them all connected to the router all the time and timing is very important, that’s why i dont need to check if the light has changed color or if it is active.

Thank you for your help in advanced

Comment: It's not clear whether you want these sequenced, or whether you want them all to be fired as fast as possible.  You can't have both.  Think it through... you either choose to wait on something, or not, but you can't both wait and not-wait at the same time.

Comment: I want it as fast as possible. Order is not important if the send phase completes all the needed hosts.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to do it is using the standard NodeJS built in `http` module:

```
const http = require('http')

const hosts = ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2'];

for (const host of hosts) {
    http.get(`http://${host}`)
}
```

This method "blindly" sends the request to all the hosts in the `hosts` array, without awaiting the response.

Comment: @Dimitry, is this async? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joãozinho Yes, each call `get()` is async and does not block. You could specify callbacks to process the result of the calls. Those would be handled asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you very much i will try it tomorrow and give some feedback to see if it improved.

Comment: Dmitry i think that it did improve or at the least it is the same. The thing is that behaviour is not constant. But it should be server side. You think that htttp.get can be faster than xmlhttprequest? Thank you very much!

Comment: http.get and xmlhttprequest should be about the same, overhead coming from the network.